# cgit error, apache/cgit doesn't interpret .lua file

Tags: lua, apache2, cgit

I'm using gitolite as my git base with cgit as my front-end and its lua-based auth-filter so that not everyone can see all repos.
But I have a problem with the configuration of lua and cgit on the apache2 server.
The main cgit configuration works but it doesn't recognize the .lua files when using the authentication-filters by adding following line to the cgitrc:

```
auth-filter=/usr/lib/cgit/filters/simple-authentication.lua
```

The error I get from apache2 error.log is:

```
AH01215: /usr/lib/cgit/filters/simple-authentication.lua: 1: : /usr/lib/cgit/cgit.cgi 
AH01215: --: not found: /usr/lib/cgit/cgit.cgi 
AH01215: : /usr/lib/cgit/cgit.cgi 
AH01215: /usr/lib/cgit/filters/simple-authentication.lua: 2: --: not found: /usr/lib/cgit/cgit.cgi 
AH01215: /usr/lib/cgit/filters/simple-authentication.lua: 3: --: not found: /usr/lib/cgit/cgit.cgi 
AH01215: /usr/lib/cgit/filters/simple-authentication.lua: 4: --: not found: /usr/lib/cgit/cgit.cgi 
AH01215: /usr/lib/cgit/filters/simple-authentication.lua: 6: Syntax error: newline unexpected: /usr/lib/cgit/cgit.cgi
```

This is my cgit part in the apache2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *80:>
        LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so
        LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cgit

        ScriptAlias /cgit "/usr/lib/cgit/cgit.cgi"
        Alias /cgit-css "usr/share/cgit/"
        <Directory "/home/git/repositories">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
                DirectoryIndex /cgit
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                
                RewriteEngine on
        </Directory>

        <Directory "/var/www/html/cgit">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgit/">

                <Files "*.lua">
                        SetHandler lua-script
                </Files>
                Options +ExecCGI
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
                DirectoryIndex /cgit 
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I enabled the cgi and lua mods for apache (with a2enmod) and apt installed luajit, lua-posix and luaossl.

I'm not really sure how to fix this problem but maybe somebody had or will have this problem aswell and knows how to fix it.

Greetings,
Yaz